# How to pass file path to a function as an argument in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

I want to take file from different directory and pass it to a function as an argument. I have been at this for hours but I can not get it to work. So far I have tried this

```
#!/bin/bash

myfile=/home/$USER/Desktop/Programs/Files/asd.bam

 function mate()
{ 
    samtools index $arg

    echo "$arg"
 }

mate $myfile
```

I check argument with echo command but It shows empty.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you really been searching on this topic? Even a simple [google search](https://www.google.pl/search?q=bash+function+arguments) gives a lot of info?

Comment: Yes I have and I wrote, I have been trying to get it work for hours. Maybe I am dim-witted or something.

Comment: Hm, ok. Just replace `$arg` with `$1`. Ex `echo "$1"`. And it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined `arg` and hence its is empty (undefined). `$1` within the function will be the first argument passed.

```
function mate()
{ 
    arg="$1"
    samtools index "$arg"
    echo "$arg"
}
```